# Using cURL to post an image to express server

Tags: image, express, curl

I have made a simple image server, however I am unable to receive the images I post to it using cURL. What am I doing wrong?

This is the server:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.listen(6692, () => {
    console.log(`Success! Your application is running on port 6692.`);
});

app.post('/upload',  function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file)
    res.send('File uploaded!');
});
```

(When I attempt to log req.file in the above code, it's undefined)

And this is the command (There is indeed a file called Untitled.png in the folder I'm running the command in):
`curl -T Untitled.png localhost:6692/upload -X POST`

Comment: If you want `req.file` filled automatically, you need a package like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to upload files with a POST request, as you would do with an HTML form. But then you must use `curl -F file=@Untitled.png localhost:6692/upload`, assuming the form field is named `file`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen `MulterError: Unexpected field`, with ```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.listen(6692, () => {
    console.log(`Success! Your application is running on port 6692.`);
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.file)
    res.send('File uploaded!');
});
```

Comment: What request did you try? `curl -F image=@Untitled.png localhost:6692/upload`? The field is called `image` in your case.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen It works! How would I go about saving that file to disk?

Comment: See [`multer` storage options](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#user-content-storage).

Comment: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Temp\my-uploads\image-1654711849409-460426282'` When using the example form the multer npm page ---- never mind! I got it working

Answer (score 0):

For uploading file through curl use this -

```
curl -F image=@Untitled.png localhost:6692/upload
```

Here `image` is the file params name.